# How do I delete a Bitcoin full node from my hard drive?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I was using Bitcoin Core as my wallet (recently installed), but a couple of hours of syncronizing, all of a sudden, I have no space at all in my hard drive. I deleted bitcoin Core, but that did nothing. What files do I need to delete?

Answer (score 7):

Before you delete you Bitcoin data from your hard drive, ensure that you have backed up the `wallet.dat` file, or you risk losing your bitcoins in case you received them on the addresses generated by Bitcoin-Core.

### Ubuntu

The most easy way to remove Bitcoin-Core from Ubuntu is by running:

`sudo apt-get remove bitcoind`.

When you run `bitcoind`, it typically (by default) creates a .bitcoin directory in the home directory of the running user unless you have explicitly specified the `datadir` to where the software will download the blocks and other data. If you're not sure where this path is, you could run the following command to help find it:

`sudo locate .bitcoin`.

After finding the path you can purge the entire directory by running the command: `sudo rm -rf /path/to/.bitcoin`.

### Windows

Navigate to `Start --> control panel --> programs and features` and scroll down the list to where bitcoin core/bitcoin-qt is listed, right click and click "uninstall or change a program" and then try uninstalling it that way.

In Windows, by default the block data is stored in the directory `C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin`. If you want to delete the entire existence of Bitcoin blockchain from your machine, you can delete the entire folder.

Finally, run regedit (win + r -> regedit). In the search, enter bitcoin and delete all entries matching the list.